# Is there a remote shutter release for the Panasonic DMC-FZ40?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, remote, shutter-release

A friend has the DMC-FZ40. Discussing Lightpainting, he was interested in buying a wireless control. Looking around for one we found out none exists, and after researching Itai's [neocamera](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/panasonic/fz40) and dpreview (for the FZ30 and FZ50), we concluded that the FZ40 is not designed for remote shooting.

Has anyone overcome this problem? Any alternative (mod?) for remote - wired or wireless?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use the camera's timer mode to trigger the shutter, so you have, say 10 seconds to get into position to start light painting.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the general advice I could find on the net.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use a timer, you can fashion a remote with a old mechanical, plunge style, shutter cable, a U shaped bracket, a servo, and a microcontroller.  But its probably MUCH easier to use a timer.

- Get a U shaped bracket that fits approximately from the tripod camera mount to the shutter button.
- Drill a hole and screw it into the tripod mount.
- Drill a hole in the bracket on top and mount a shutter release cable so that it plunges on to the shutter release button.
- On the other end of the cable, have a servo that plunges and releases the cable.
- Control the servo with your microcontroller.

Comment: LOL... better replace your camera... Anyway, if you're going mechanical, then you may be able to avoid the servo/MC part by using an old-school shutter release cable.

Comment: Well, with a MC you can also make it an intervalometer or wireless remote.  This answer was intended less as a 'You should do it this way.' and more for 'It is *possible*, especially if you're already handy with that kind of tech.'.  I've seen this setup done before.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some crazy DIY stuff in my life...