# Need more detail on the mechanical shutter release diy for Panasonic FZ40

Tags: equipment-recommendation, remote, shutter-release, panasonic-lumix

I read [an answer from rfusca about how to make a mechanical shutter release for the Panasonic DMC-FZ40](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/13417/11371). I can picture what you're saying in my head but I'm not sure what parts to buy. There are a ton of shutter release cables on the market, and as for the servo and microcontroller...I don't know where to even start.

I like your idea...a pretty cool work-around. Will you please provide some options for the parts you think will work? Some specific manufacturer/model/part numbers? And can you provide a bit more instructional detail please? I won't have a problem putting it together; I've built laser systems in a past career so I'm pretty sure I can make this work.

Comment: Could you add a link to the answer to which you're referring? That'd add some context so that someone else might be able to help even if @rfusca doesn't chime in.

Comment: @Caleb I made a hopefully intelligent guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to totally design it yourself.  Take a look at this link for some ideas: [mechanical shutter release Google Search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mechanical%20shutter%20release&rlz=1C1VFKB_enCA640CA640&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=687&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF9LD88bPKAhXD1R4KHf4RCEsQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=mechanical%20shutter%20release%20servo)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]